# Can we find such a map $f$ so that $f$ pushforward $\mu$ to $\nu$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

For two Dirac measures $\mu=\frac{2}{3}\delta_1+\frac{1}{3}\delta_2$ (concentrated on two points $1$ and $2$) and $\nu=\frac{1}{3}(\delta_0+\delta_1+\delta_2)$ (concentrated on three points $0$, $1$ ,and $2$).

Recall that we say a map $f$ pushforward $\mu$ to $\nu$ means $\mu(f^{-1}(A))=\nu(A)$ for any Borel measurable subsets $A \in R$.

My question is can we find such a map $f$ so that $f$ pushforward $\mu$ to $\nu$? The answer seems to be no. But how to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose such an $f$ exists and let $A = \{0\}$.  Then
$$\mu(f^{-1}(A)) = \nu(A) = \frac 13$$ so that $1 \notin f^{-1}(A)$ and $2 \in f^{-1}(A)$. In particular $f(2) = 0$.

A similar argument shows $f(2) =1$, yielding a contradiction.